# How to get dropdown value from database through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

This code is used to create dynamic row in table & in this code dropdown value should be feel from database Please tell me how to fill dropdown for this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){

        // var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td><td><input type='text' name=''></td>";
         var markup = "<tr class='item-row'><td align='center'>"+
               "<input  name='record' type='checkbox'>"+
              "</td> <td align='center'>"+
                "<div class='form-group'>"+
                  "<select name='item_select1' id='item_select1' class='form-control' onchange='item_value();'>"+
                    "<option value='' disabled selected>---Select---</option>"+
                  "<option value='1'>+Add New Item</option>"+
                "</select><br />"+
                "<textarea id='item_description' name='item_description'></textarea></div></td>"+
               "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='item_unit' id='item_unit' placeholder='Display Name ...'></td>"+        
             "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='item_rate' id='item_rate' placeholder='Display Name ...'></td> "+                
              "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='item_discount' id='item_discount' placeholder='Discount %'></td>"+                 
             "<td align='center'><div class='form-group'>"+
                  "<select name='item_tax_id1' id='item_tax_id1' class='form-control' onchange='tax_value();'>"+
                    "<option value='' disabled selected>---Select---</option>"+
                  "<option value=''>+Add New Item</option></select></div></td>"+
                  "<td align='center'><label name='item_amount' id='item_amount'></label></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("1 tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
          if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Im sorry, dropdown is not a feeling. So you can't feel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (index, elem) {
            $("#drpId").append("<option value=\"" + elem.value+ "\">" + elem.name+ "</option>");
        });
            }
        },
        error: function (errMsg) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please help me how to fetch record from database inside json

Comment: Look at the there is, write your url like `url:"pagename/methodname"` and you will get response  in  `success: function (json) {
           
        });` method

Comment: I have try this ..But unable to get response from json

Comment: Are you able to making call?,if not then what error is coming

Comment: please tell me how to get value from json

Comment: You can not get value from json you can get value through ajax , json is data format, and check above comment what is mentioned .

Comment: I was tried a lot but unable to get json response  from ajax.php file.......  url of my file.
<?php   include('../dbconnection/comp_connect.php');
$qry_item = "SELECT item_id, item_name FROM item";
$view_item = $conn->prepare($qry_item);
$view_item->execute();
while ($rs_item = $view_item->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$data[] = ['value' => $rs_item['item_id'], 'name' => $rs_item['item_name']];
}echo json_encode($data);?>